# Django template not rendering date even with template filter

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't figure out what it is.  I have a model, EntryDate:

```
class EntryDate(models.Model):
    dateWorked = models.DateTimeField('date worked')
    employeeid = models.IntegerField()
```

I then try to render the dateWorked field in a template, like so:

```
    {% for ed in entryDates %}
        <li class="entryDate">
            {{ ed.employeeid }} | {{ ed.dateWorked|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

What I get is "employeeid | ", or with real data "12345 | ".  I've checked in sqlite and there is a date in the model (obviously, it's a required field).  Why won't my datetime model field render in the template?  I'm using Django 1.4

UPDATE:
The shell turns out to be useful :-).  I'm getting a DateTimeField received a naive datetime warning, and when I query the objects dateWorked field, it returns None.  I don't really need timezone support, but why would it return None?  How do I resolve the issue of a valid datetime in sqlite being returned as None to django?

Comment: Have you tried to print the date without the template filter?

Comment: Yes.  That's what led me to the documentation originally, as it didn't print without the filter.